# How to store mouse coordinates in GDI+?

Tags: winapi, gdi+

I wanted to ask if a POINT structure is the only way to store mouse coordinates ? My problem with this way is that when you declare:

```
POINT ps[20];
```

you need to have a fixed size array. What if I need to store more points ? Is there a way to make it dynamic (to resize itself when it reaches the limit). I want to use this array to get mouse coordinates and then draw lines in WM_PAINT: message. thx

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
{
   pt[i].x=LOWORD(lparam);
   pt[i++].y=HIWORD(lparam);
 --------
}
```

Comment: Use standard resizable data structures supported by the language you use.  A `vector<Point>` in C++, a linked list in C.

Comment: @Hans: Why would a linked list be a good idea in C but not C++?

Comment: There's nothing in your question that's specific to storing mouse coordinates, Windows, or GDI+.  Your question is really: How can I store a dynamic amount of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use an array of POINT structures.